# When I Run My Python Code My Python Just Closes

Tags: python

When I open my .py file with this code in it, it shows for a brief second then disappears. How do I fix this so I can see the output?

```
print "Hello welcome to Mcdonald's how may I help you"
print "Type 1 for food"
print "Type 2 for drinks"
user_input = input ("Type 3 for money")
if (user_input) == 1:
    print "We have Hamburgers, fries, and cancer"
    print "Type 1 for hamburgers"
    print "Type 2 for fries"
    user_input = input ("Type 3 cancer")
    if (user_input) == 1:
        print "That will cost you $1.25"
        print "Type 1 to pay"
        user_input = input ("Type 2 to steal")
        if (user_input) == 1:
            user_input = input ("Thank you for comming")
        elif (user_input) == 2:
           user_input = input ("HEY COME BACK AND PAY!") 
    elif (user_input) == 2:
        user_input = input ("Potato!")
    elif (user_input) == 3:
        user_input = input ("Sorry we are out of cancer")
if (user_input) == 2:
    print "We have Coke, and Pepsi"
    print "Type 1 for Coke"
    user_input = input ("Type 2 for Pepsi")
    if (user_input) == 1:
        user_input = input ("COKE SUCKS NO DRINKS FOR YOU!!!!!")
    elif (user_input) == 2: 
        print "Nice I LOVE Pepsi Coke sucks that will cost you $1.00"
        print "Type 1 to pay"
        user_input = input ("Type 2 to steal")
        if (user_input) == 2:
            user_input = input ("HEY COME BACK AND PAY!")
if (user_input) == 3:
    print "So heres the plan you take the register ill destract the others."
    print "Type 1 To call the cops"
    user_input = input ("Type 2 to do the plan")
    if (user_input) == 1:
        user_input = input ("You got $150 for calling the cops")
    elif (user_input) == 2:
        user_input = input ("You got $150 for doing the plan")
else:
    print "Sorry I did not get your order"
```

Comment: *"Python just closes"* - Are you using windows? and double-clicking the file in the windows explorer? If yes then you will either have to learn how to use the command line or add something to pause execution at the end of your program (e.g.: an `input()`)

Comment: Also please (learn to) format your code properly, there's options that do most of it automatically when creating questions

Comment: Also if you want to paste code here, please do it with the "input code" button. It is unreadable now.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Windows. If you want to see the output, I suggest you open a command prompt in the directory containing the Python script you want to execute and then try running `python <your script>.py`.

If you have the directory open in a file explorer (which I guess you do if you're double-clicking the file), a quick shortcut is to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + right-click within the file explorer and select "Open command window here" to open the prompt in that directory.

Answer (score -1):

Open cmd:
Start -> cmd (in "Search programs and files") and run your script in this.